# Solr Custom Transfomer Not Working?

Tags: java, solr, solr5

I am trying to Add Few Fields to solr  Index While indexing with  Data Import Handler.

Below is My data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                 url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" user="*****" password="*********"/>
    <script><![CDATA[
        function addMergedPdt(row)
        {
            var m = row.get('mergedPdt');
            if(m == null)
            {
                row.put('mergedPdt',9999999999); 
            }       
            return row;
        }


            ]]></script>

    <script><![CDATA[
        function transform(row)   
        {

            if(row.get(mergedPdt) == null)
            {
                row.put('catStock', 0);
                row.put('catPxMrp',0);
                row.put('catPrice',0);
                row.put('catCount',1)
                row.put('catRating',0);
                row.put('catAval',0);
                return row;
            }
            else
            {
                row.put('catAval',1);
                return row;
            }

        }
    ]]></script>


<document>
    <entity name="product" onError="continue" transformer="script:addMergedPdt" query="select p.id, name, image, stock, lower(p.seller) as seller, brand, 
        cast(price as signed) as price, cast(pxMrp as signed) as pxMrp, mergedPdt, shipDays, url, cast(rating as signed) as rating, 
        disc(price, pxMrp) as discount, mc.node as seller_cat, oc.node as cat, substring_index(oc.node, '|', 1) as cat1, 
        substring(substring_index(oc.node, '|', 2), length(substring_index(oc.node, '|', 1)) + 2) as cat2, 
        substring(substring_index(oc.node, '|', 3), length(substring_index(oc.node, '|', 2)) + 2) as cat3  
        from _products as p, _mergedCat as mc, _ourCat as oc where active = 1 and cat_id = mc.id and ourCat = oc.id and 
        ('${dataimporter.request.full}' != 'false' OR last_visited &gt; '${dataimporter.last_index_time}') limit 10000">
    <!-- To Papulate the Catalog Data -->
    <entity name="mergedPdt" transformer="script:transform"  onError="continue" query = "SELECT mergedPdt,count(*) as catCount,cast(max(stock) as signed) as catStock,cast(max(pxMrp) as signed) as catPxMrp,cast(min(price) as signed) as catPrice,cast(avg(rating) as signed) as catRating FROM `_products` where mergedPdt = ${product.mergedPdt}"/>
 </entity>
```

I am Getting some Error Like

org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Error invoking script for entity mergedPdt Processing Document # 10000
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:70)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ScriptTransformer.transformRow(ScriptTransformer.java:59)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.applyTransformer(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:198)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextRow(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:256)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:475)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:514)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:414)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:329)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:232)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:416)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:480)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:461)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: transform
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invoke(RhinoScriptEngine.java:286)
    at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine.invokeFunction(RhinoScriptEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ScriptTransformer.transformRow(ScriptTransformer.java:55)
    ... 10 more

and all fields are being Indexed excluding the extra fields which i tried adding using the transformer.
And surprisingly only one field "catCount" has been indexed.

You can trust me and i am confident  regarding the schema definition and other configurations.

any lead will be higly appriciated ??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried to just have a single script block? I also think you'd probably want the script block just inside dataConfig, not dataSource.

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes ,I tried.And i think the  script is inside the dataConfig only as the dataSource ended just above it .